# Change SELECT of closed (but not deallocated) CURSOR

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle, cursor

I found this statement [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cursor_(databases)):

> "After closing a cursor, a program can open it again, which implies
>   that the DBMS re-evaluates the same query or a different query and
>   builds a new result set."

Can you do this in SQL Server? I didn't find anything related to this on the Transact-SQL Cursor page.

Do other DBMSs support such a feature?

Comment: Generally speaking you shouldn't be using a cursor in the first place. They have their place but they are very rare.

Comment: You can do this http://rextester.com/AZZS83915.

Comment: Use Martin's example, change the second query from sys.sysobjects to sys.sysindexes and you've changed the original structure.

Comment: I appreciate your comment, Sean Lange, but it answers a different question. I'll keep that in mind, thanks!

Comment: I see, so you can do so by using a cursor variable. Thanks Martin Smith & Lee Everest!
But is it possible to declare a server cursor with DECLARE crs CURSOR, process its result set, CLOSE it (not DEALLOCATE it) and change its SELECT?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW. For SQL Server. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/close-transact-sql

> CLOSE leaves the data structures available for reopening, but fetches
>   and positioned updates are not allowed until the cursor is reopened.
>   CLOSE must be issued on an open cursor; CLOSE is not allowed on
>   cursors that have only been declared or are already closed.

**Syntax**

```
CLOSE { { [ GLOBAL ] cursor_name } | cursor_variable_name }
```

**Arguments**

*GLOBAL*

Specifies that cursor_name refers to a global cursor.

*cursor_name*

Is the name of an open cursor. If both a global and a local cursor exist with cursor_name as their name, cursor_name refers to the global cursor when GLOBAL is specified; otherwise, cursor_name refers to the local cursor.

*cursor_variable_name*

Is the name of a cursor variable associated with an open cursor.

Comment: My question was whether after closing a cursor, but before deallocating it, you can change its SELECT statement, the one you used in the cursor's DECLARE statement. The link I provided clearly says it's possible, but I didn't find a way to do it in SQL Server. And I was curious whether maybe other DBMSs support this.